# how to make lines in the bottom of sink

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

I want to make these lines in the bottom of the sink. I tried, but I couldn't make them. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do it? I am sharing my blender file screenshots in wireframe and with material.enter image description here

[image]

any suggestion
[image]

Comment: in your reference image the middle piece is square, do you want it square or circular like in your mesh?

Comment: did you try edge crease?

Answer (score 2):

Create a plane, subdivide it, inset:

[image]

Move down the inset:

[image]

Extrude up the borders:

[image]

Bevel these edges:

[image]

If you need to make the center circular (?), inset the center, then right click > *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

Work the topology a bit, etc:

[image]